# Contract deploy problem in Zksync era network

Tags: solidity, zksync

Createfactory and transparentproxy have 2 contracts. I am facing some problems while deploying on zksync era network.

1- I'm using ethers version 5.7.2. When I deploy like this, I get this error " Return Error => ProviderError: Failed to serialize transaction: toAddressIsNull ".

2- When I use the "hardhat-zksync-upgradable" plugin to solve the above error, it says that I need to update to ethers 6.1 version. When I update, I cannot compile any contract.

Comment: did you find any solution to this?